# C#, Foreach Item In

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have a Listbox, which houses some items. The Items are Grids which house a variety of Textblocks, buttons, etc etc.

```
foreach (Grid thisGrid in myListBox.SelectedItems)
                        {
                                foreach (TextBlock thisTextblock in thisGrid.Children)
                                {
                                     //Do Somthing
                                }
                        }
```

Yet this throws an exception because there are other items than Textblock's in there. How can I accomodate this? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that the `foreach` doesn't *filter* all TextBlocks but it treats every child as if it were a TextBlock (with a cast) - and that apparently isn't correct in your case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I read it, the problem here is with the *inner* loop, and there being things in `Children` that are not `TextBlock`s.

If LINQ is available:

```
foreach (TextBlock thisTextblock in thisGrid.Children.OfType<TextBlock>()) {
    // ... do something here
}
```

otherwise:

```
foreach (object child in thisGrid.Children) {
    TextBlock thisTextblock = child as TextBlock;
    if(thisTextblock  == null) continue;
    // ... do something here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked great! Thanks to everyone else that contributed.

Answer (score 3):

you could try

```
foreach (TextBlock thisTextblock in thisGrid.Children.Where(c => c is TextBlock))
{ /* ... */ }
```

for your inner loop.

**EDIT**: TIL, that this can also be written as:

```
foreach (TextBlock in thisTextblock in thisGrid.Children.OfType<TextBlock>());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var thisTextblock in thisGrid.Children)
                            {
                                 if(thisTextblock is Textblock)
                                     //Do Somthing
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If LINQ is available try that:

```
thisGrid.Children.OfType<TextBlock>().ToList().ForEach(tb =>
{
...your code here
});
```